# Why do I get a syntax error in my compound if statement?

Tags: perl

Why do I get a syntax error in the following script?

```
print "Enter Sequence:";
$a = <STDIN>;

if ($a=="A")|| ($a== "T")|| ( $a == "C")|| ($a== "G")
{
    print $a;
}
else
{
    print "Error";
}
```

Comment: What is chomp? I still get )|| error in that?

Comment: So embarassing :( I am just asking the user for inputting A G C T if he doesn't enter those then it will return error! if he enters it will return the input

Comment: The else is not working , It just throws whatever I print

Comment: print "Enter Sequence:";
   $a = <STDIN>;
   if ($a=="A" || $a== "T" || $a == "C" || $a== "G")
   {
   print $a;
   }
   else
   {
   print "Error";
    }

Answer (score 7):

First, you have a syntax error: The condition expression of an `if` statement must be in parens.

The second error is found by using `use strict; use warnings;`, something you should always do. The error is the use of numerical comparison (`==`) where string comparison (`eq`) is called for.

The final problem is that `$a` will almost surely contain a string ending with a newline, so a `chomp` is in order.

Comment: print "Enter Sequence:";
 $a = <STDIN>;
 if ($a=="A" || $a== "T" || $a == "C" || $a== "G")
 {
 print $a;
 }
 else
 {
 print "Error";
 }

Comment: @user3434415: you want `$a = <STDIN>; chomp $a; if ( $a eq "A" || ...`

Comment: So you've fixed the first error, but you're still not using `use strict; use warnings;`, `eq` and `chomp`.

Comment: I am just asking the user for inputting A G C T if he doesn't enter those then it will return error! if he enters it will return the input. But it just throws away whatever input he has entered

Answer (score 7):

The immediate problem is that he *entire* logical expression for an `if` must be in parentheses.

In addition

- You must use `eq` instead of `==` for comparing strings
- Your input string will have a trailing newline, so it will look like `"C\n"` and will not match a simple one-character string. You need to `chomp` the input before you compare it
- It is generally better to read from STDIN using `<>` rather than `<STDIN>`. That way you can specify an input file on the command line, or read from the STDIN if no input was provided
- You *must always* put `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of your program. That will catch many simple errors that you may otherwise overlook
- You shouldn't use `$a` as a variable name. It is a symbol reserved by Perl itself, and says nothing about the purpose of the variable
- It is best to use a regular expression for simple comparisons like this. It makes your code much easier to read and will usually make the execution very much faster

Please take a look at this program, which I think does what you want.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter Sequence: ";
my $input = <>;
chomp $input;

if ( $input =~ /^[ATCG]$/i ) {
  print $input, "\n";
}
else {
  print "Error";
}
```